# KeyNotFoundException from cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm using Razor in my asp.net application. From my controller I put in the ViewBag, a Dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<int, RisposteUtente> mappaRisposte = (Dictionary<int, RisposteUtente>)Session["mappaRisposte"];
            if (mappaRisposte == null)
                mappaRisposte = new Dictionary<int, RisposteUtente>();
            ViewBag.mappaRisposte = mappaRisposte;
```

So I want to retreive the value of this dictionary from the cshtml file. So I'm build this code:

```
        var oggetto = ((Dictionary<int, AnalisiHRVElaborazioni.Models.Response.RisposteUtente>)ViewBag.mappaRisposte)[x.rowId];
        if (oggetto != null)
        {
               <script>
                   alert("oggetto " + oggetto.valore);
               </script>

        }
```

So if I try to start this code, I have this error:

```
Exception detail: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The specified key was not present in the dictionary.
```

So how can I manage this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error message states that the specified key is not found. Odds are you are passing in a value from `x.rowId` that is not valid/doesn't exist in the dictionary; this is basically like an array index out of bounds error. You should check if the key exists first:

```cs
var dictionary = ((Dictionary<int, AnalisiHRVElaborazioni.Models.Response.RisposteUtente>)ViewBag.mappaRisposte);
var oggetto = dictionary.ContainsKey(x.rowId) ? dictionary[x.rowId] : null;
```

You already have a null check in place so this should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `TryGetValue` method for check null key.

**instead of this**

```
var value = myDict[myKey];
```

**change to**

```
if (!myDict.TryGetValue(myKey, out data)) {
    Debug.LogError("myDict doesn't have the value");
}
else {
    //do whatever you were planning to do
}
```

**in your case**

```
var myDict = (Dictionary<int, RisposteUtente>)ViewBag.mappaRisposte;
var oggetto = myDict.TryGetValue(x.rowId, out data) ? data : null;
```